# AlarmManager, repeating alarms and daylight saving

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I scheduled an alarm, that triggers every day at the same hour. I set it as repeating alarm (using [`AlarmManager.setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)) and it triggers every `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds (24 hours). I don't know if I must control daylight saving time changes, or it's automatic.

I tested this with:

1. I changed mobile device time to one minute before daylight saving time change (`1:59`) (change is from 2 am to 3 am).
2. I scheduled an alarm to `3:01`.
3. I waited 2 minutes, and the alarm fired OK.

But if I set this alarm that runs every day, for example, 2 days before daylight saving time change... It would run as expected after daylight saving time change? Or do I need to control it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a TIMEZONE_CHANGED receiver and reshedule your alarms (stop and restart)

```
<receiver android:name="RecevierTimeZoneChange">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"></action>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dodge. I'll test, and I'll mark your answer as accepted if it works! :D

Comment: I tested it. It works when I change timezone manually, but when it changes automatically because of daylight saving time change, it doesn't fire :( so I can't reschedule my alarms :'(

Comment: hmm, thats bad... then i have no idea. sorry :(

Comment: Should it not be ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED

Comment: no, ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED is the constant in the Intent(you could use this in code with Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED). the actual content of that constant is android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED as you can see in the "Constant Value:" line of the doc you linked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TIME_TICK intent also.
This intent is fired in each change of time on Android.
Also by minors corrections automatically done by network.